# Django: Show link based on model field value

Tags: python, django

I want the "Admin" link to display based on a field in my `UserLevels` model called "access_level". If the currently logged in user's access_level field is equal to "admin" then the "Admin" link should display.

Currently there are no errors however the "Admin" link will display for every logged in user and not take into account the access_level field value.

HTML:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and userlevels.access_level == 'admin' %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'adminpanel:widgets' %}">Admin</a>
{% endif %}
```

Adminpanel app models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

    class UserLevels(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)

        access_level = models.CharField(max_length=5,default='user',blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.userlevels.access_level == 'admin' %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'adminpanel:widgets' %}">Admin</a>
{% endif %}
```

but is better if you pass that in your view and not in the template

Comment: I will, but it makes me wait 4 minute to do that

Comment: Also why is it better if I do that in the view vs the template?

Comment: somethings you can't use some parameter in the templates Django system, that's the reason

Comment: Gotcha, but it doesn't raise a security issue does it?

Comment: No it doesn't .

Answer (score 1):

`userlevel` is not valid on its own. It is a property of user, which is set by the fact that you created a `oneToOne` field.

Try

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.userlevels.access_level == 'admin' %}
   <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'adminpanel:widgets' %}">Admin</a>
{% endif %}
```